# Bootstrap html, trying to make a dark table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I was looking at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/ and I saw the bg really dark table near the bottom. I took the code and put it into a html doc, it did not work. I played around the the code a bit, still nothing.

How would I get the table?

Help please!

Code ( from the site ) :

```
<!-- On rows -->
<tr class="bg-primary">...</tr>
<tr class="bg-success">...</tr>
<tr class="bg-warning">...</tr>
<tr class="bg-danger">...</tr>
<tr class="bg-info">...</tr>

<!-- On cells (`td` or `th`) -->
<tr>
  <td class="bg-primary">...</td>
  <td class="bg-success">...</td>
  <td class="bg-warning">...</td>
  <td class="bg-danger">...</td>
  <td class="bg-info">...</td>
</tr>
```

I can get it so it becomes a light table, but the way that I want it, which is on the page is dark.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: ok @Ofisora I will edit it now

Comment: Did you include a reference to `bootstrap` css file between `<head>` and `</head>`?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to create a dark table you can use it in the following way:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

if for some reason the bootstrap class fails I advise you to define your own class in your css:

```
.table{
 background: #212529 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <caption>List of users</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope help you. Good luck

Comment: the table.dark class doesn't use black as the background color but rather the hex value of #212529 just wanted to point that out you might wanna change it

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the necessary files inside your HTML documents?

I have just tried the code on my side and it is working perfectly fine.

The following is my output from the segment of code that you have given:

[The output shown in my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Jdl.jpg)

If the above is what you were looking for, you may refer to the code below:

Do remember to inside your own thead tag if you intend to use it. 
For more reference, refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#table-head-options

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <body>
        <table class="table table-dark">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="bg-primary">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bg-success">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bg-warning">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bg-primary">1</td>
                    <td class="bg-success">2</td>
                    <td class="bg-warning">3</td>
                    <td class="bg-danger">4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
```